# MySQL Import Database, No Inserts

Tags: mysql, database, insert, structure, workbench

I'm using MySql Workbench and WAMP Server.  I have a database on the server and when I click reverse engineering on the workbench it imports the db structure, but not any of the inserts.  What do I do to get the db data as well as the structure into the workbench.

Also on a separate point as I was using workbench, i noticed it did not automatically sync with the db on the server, ie. when i insert a new row, it did not reflect in the server.. must I forward engineer the db to the server every time i make a change?  So sorry for my lack of understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySql Workbench reverse engineering is only to obtain the Schema of the database.

If you want to search the database, make backups, obtain the schema and much more then you can use [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php).  There are some installers which configures the whole system to work with WAMP enviromment and includes it, like [Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/es/xampp.html) or [ZendServer](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/);

[image]

Comment: another good database GUI is SQLYog Community Edition... it's free and does all the above... except create a model of the schema.. so ill keep the workbench around just for that... thnx for your help.. :)